# ActionScript 3 Game - Matching questions and answers

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, scripting, addeventlistener

I am very new to flash and action script and I am making a matching game as part of a project. Basically you just match the animal print that is displayed with the corresponding animal and a score is added up ..

I have created the animal prints in photoshop, and I have them in a separate folder, I now need to display the random images with corresponding answers to this image.

I know this is a broad question and any help that is given will be greatly appreciated. The only action script I have so far is making the button click and link to the next page..

Heres the code..

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop()

gobutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startgame); 

function startgame (event:MouseEvent):void {

    gotoAndStop(2)
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered.   Is each question just a frame on your timeline with images?

Comment: For each question I want the page to refresh with the images and answers to change.. So I want the question to change but not the keyframe basically, if that is possible :p

Comment: Most things are possible, what I'm trying to say is that you should update your question to explain/show how you currently create your prints and animals and what you've tried.

Comment: So I edited the question a bit to try and explain what I need to do, so far I tried to make the images appear using this code..var randomImgNum: Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
trace(randomImgNum); 

myLoader.source = "AnimalPrints/1.jpg" + randomImgNum + ".jpg";